# Can't change width or height in electron

Tags: html, css

I'm making a electron application and trying to make a div a certain size, but it doesn't work.

I try putting width and height, but it doesn't set the width or height to what I set as the height, I tried looking in the DevTools, but it had a warning symbol.

My CSS looks like this:

```css
.price {
    background-color: #272525;
    color: white;
    width: 128; /* Doesn't work */
    height: 128; /* Doesn't work */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its undefined because the value (128) is not defined whether it's pixels, rem.. etc.
Try changing it to

width: 128px;
height: 128px;

Answer (score 1):

Add `px` after the number in the `height` and `with` properties.
You can use others like `em`, `rem`, `%`, `vw`, `vh`